# User selected rows when importing CSV to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, csv, import

Is there an accepted best practice to allow users to select the rows associated with columns when importing a CSV file in Ruby on Rails?

Such that they upload the file -> are given a confirmation screen with the list of column headers, and select inputs for each one (populated with the writeable attributes of the model)  -> save each CSV row to the model, with the columns selected in the previous step.

Basically, I want the functionality shown here:

http://youtu.be/5Ddnu_NK_-o?t=50s

The way I would go about this, were there not a better way, would be something like this:

1. User uploads file
2. Parse CSV
3. Display first several rows
4. Display a form with select inputs for each column, populated by the writeable attributes, and cached file
5. For each of the POST column name parameters, match them to the column (while verifying that no column name is used twice)
6. Create a new record for each row

I confess that steps 4 and 5 are pretty daunting to me as a newbie to RoR, and it seems like this must be encountered a fair amount, but I haven't found any luck finding gems or tutorials on the subject.